# Convert dataframe column to array and inset back into dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas data frame table like this:

| Unique ID | Count | Samples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A-1 | 3 | 6.1 (Apple) |
| A-1 | 3 | 4.5 (Banana) |
| A-1 | 3 | 5.6 (Kiwi) |
| A-2 | 2 | 7.2 (Orange) |
| A-2 | 2 | 3.6 (Mango) |

I would like to convert the column "Samples" to a list/array and obtain only the first occurrence of the other columns. The resulting table should look like this

| Unique ID | Count | SampleSummary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A-1 | 3 | 6.1 (Apple), 4.5 (Banana), 5.6 (Kiwi) |
| A-2 | 2 | 7.2 (Orange), 3.6(Mango) |

So far, this is what I have in my code:

```
for i in range(len(dataframe['unique_id'])):
     SampleSummary= np.asarray(pd.concat([dataframe['Sample']]))
```

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: What is output if change `A-2` to `A-1` ?

Comment: Ok thanks, will edit the post

Comment: There is no difference between your input sample and your output sample.

Comment: just editted the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary for aggregate by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) without column `Unique ID`, for column `Samples` aggregate by `join` by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
d = dict.fromkeys(dataframe.columns.difference(['Unique ID']), 'first')
d['Samples'] = ', '.join

df  = dataframe.groupby('Unique ID', as_index=False).agg(d)
print (df)
  Unique ID  Count                                Samples
0       A-1      3  6.1 (Apple), 4.5 (Banana), 5.6 (Kiwi)
1       A-2      2              7.2 (Orange), 3.6 (Mango)
```

Or is possible use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for column filled by joined strings and then use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
dataframe['Samples'] = dataframe.groupby('Unique ID')['Samples'].transform(', '.join)
df = dataframe.drop_duplicates('Unique ID')
print (df)
  Unique ID  Count                                Samples
0       A-1      3  6.1 (Apple), 4.5 (Banana), 5.6 (Kiwi)
3       A-2      2              7.2 (Orange), 3.6 (Mango)
```

Comment: I used the OR solution and it's exactly what I need. Thanks!